# python map function with dictionaries in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science

```
def card (Name,F_Name,Roll_No,Program):    

    x= f'''
    University Name
    
    
    Name: {Name}
    Father Name: {F_Name}
    Roll No: {Roll_No}
    Program: {Program}

    '''
    return x

data = [{'Name':'Student1','F_Name':"student's 1 father",'Roll_No':'123','Program':'BSCS'},{'Name':'student2','F_Name:':"student's 2 father",'Roll_No':'456','Program':'BSCS'},{'Name':'student3','F_Name':"student's 3 father",'Roll_No':'789','Program':'BSCS'}]

id_card = list(map(card,**data))

print (id_card)
```

I want to run this function using the map function and iterate the dictionary value in their respective positions in the user defined function.

Comment: You have a typo: `'F_Name:'` should be `'F_Name'`

Answer (score 3):

`map()` can't spread the dictionaries itself. `**data` requires `data` to be a dictionary, not a list of dictionaries. Use a `lambda` to spread the dictionary during each call.

```
id_card = list(map(lambda d: card(**d), data))
```

or use a list comprehension:

```
id_card = [card(**d) for d in data]
```